# Instance variable in Stripes

Tags: instance-variables, init, stripes

I'm trying to find a way to create an instance variable within the Stripes application context.
Something that i would do in the `init()` method of a Servlet while using hand-coded servlets.
The problem is that since an instance of the `ActionBean` is created each time the application is accessed, the variable in the actionBean is created multiple time.
I have tried to get some reasonable place withing Stripes trying to call the `ServletContext` via `ActionBeanContext.getServletContext()`, but from there there is no way to access the `init()` method and write some code in it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Aren't you just asking how to create an application wide variable? (that's what you usually do in servlet's `init()` method). That's quite different from instance variable.

Comment: Hi Balus, indeed, were do you place an application wide variable in Stripes, i'm still searching, no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ActionBeanContext](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/ActionBeanContext.html) is also Stripes application context. This context can be customized and can contain whatever you want. Some example code:

```
package my.app;

public class CustomActionBeanContext extends ActionBeanContext {
  public CustomActionBeanContext() {
    super();
  }

  public MyObject getMyObject() {
      return (MyObject) getServletContext().getAttribute(“myObject”);
  }

  // Alternative solution without ServletContextListner
  private static MyObject2 myObject2;
  static {
     myObject2 = new MyObject2();
  }

  public MyObject2 getMyObject2() {
      return myObject2;
  }
}
```

To let the [Stripes context factory](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Configuration+Reference#ConfigurationReference-ActionBeanContextFactoryProperties) know you want to use a custom ActionBeanContext you need to add an init-param to the Stripes filter in the web.xml:

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionBeanContext.Class</param-name>
        <param-value>my.app.CustomActionBeanContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

You can initialize your object at server start by adding a SerlvetContextListener:

```
Public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
@Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("myObject", new MyObject());
}
```

Example ActionBean:

```
public class MyAction implements ActionBean {
  private CustomActionBeanContext context;

  @Override
  public CustomActionBeanContext getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  @Override
  public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) {
    this.context = (CustomActionBeanContext) context;
  }

  @DefaultHandler
  public Resolution view() {
    MyObject  myObject = getContext().getMyObject();
    // doing something usefull with it..
  }
}
```

**An alternative solution, in my opinion a superiour solution, is to use a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework for injecting the ([singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) objects into your actionbeans. See Stripes configuration example here: [Injecting Stripes ActionBeans with Guice DI](http://kdeveloper.com/guice-managed-action-beans/)**

Comment: Hi KDeveloper and thx for the advise, i forgot to close the case the other day, i actually solved it simply inserting the object i need in the servlet context like so getContext().getServletContext().setAttribute(key,value);

Comment: In that case don't forget that setAttribute is not thread safe, so you need to set/get the attribute in synchronized code that's why it's safer to use ServletContextListener as it runs before any request.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Stripes-specific way, but using the standard Servlet API you'd implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do the job in `contextInitialized()` method. If you register it as `<listener>` in `web.xml` (or when you're already on Java EE 6, annotate using `@WebListener`), then it'll run during webapp's startup.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    event.getServletContext().setAttribute("somename", new SomeObject());
}
```

This way it's available in EL by `${somename}` and in all action beans by `ServletContext#getAttribute()`.

Comment: Thx, that looks indeed like a potential solution, the problem is "where" to implement the cintextInitialized(), i suppose this should be done in a servlet, thats my issue, since a Stripes app only contains ActionBeans i dont know where to put it. Stripes loads 1 servlet at startup, the DispatcherServlet, but its unaccessible

Comment: In your `ServletContextListener` implementation.

Comment: What i'm trying to do now is to call getServletContext().setAttribute("",o) from the ActionBeanContext, but it gives me null, thats so strange, the container initializes automatically a ServletContext

Answer (score 0):

@JBoy, You have to specify your implementation of ServletContextListner in the web.xml like below

```
<listner>
   <listner-class>
        www.test.com.MyListner
   </listner-class>
</listner>
```

Thanks KDeveloper for his advice. I was also searching for the solution. I found the information from his blog

There is one more method I have found out. For that you have to subclass the "RuntimeConfiguration" class

```
public class MyConfiguration extends RuntimeConfiguration {
     @Override
     public void init() {
         getServletContext.setAttribute("myObject",new MyObject);
         super.init();
     }
}
```

After that in the web.xml specify the above configuration.

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>Configuration.Class</param-name>
   <param-value>www.test.com.MyConfiguration</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You also have to subclass the ActionBeanContext as KDeveloper said; to get the object in ActionBeans

This is my finding. I found out it is working. But I don't know whether it has any side effects. If it has any; please comment..