# How to load a variable in the ServletContext when application initializes using stripes and guice?

Tags: guice, stripes

I have read [answer regarding loading variable when app starts in stripes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604976/instance-variable-in-stripes)

In that KDeveloper has adviced to use Guice to load singleton object instead of the other techniques he has specified. I have loaded variable using Guice. But I am not able to load the variable when application starts. I don't want the variable to be loaded whenever a new connection occurs. I want a stripes + guice specific answer.

Is anybody out there can help me out ? Thanking you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Guice singletons to start at application start, you need to bind them with **[asEagerSingleton()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/ScopedBindingBuilder.html#asEagerSingleton%28%29)** otherwise they will start on first usage. Example code::

```
package com.myapp.myguice;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(MySingleton.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }
}
```

The singleton could look like this:

```
package com.myapp.myguice;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class MySingleton {
  private String myValue;

  @Inject
  MySingleton() {
    myValue = UnkownAPI.getMyValue();
  }

  public String getMyValue() {
    return myValue;
  }
}
```

Make sure you have both [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list) and [Stripes-Guice](https://github.com/bgoodin/stripes-guice/downloads) jar files added to your project/classpath and that you have configured your web.xml like this:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>Guice.Modules</param-name>
  <param-value>com.myapp.myguice.ApplicationModule</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
  <listener-class>
    com.silvermindsoftware.stripes.integration.guice.GuiceContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you need to inject the singleton into an actionBean, then please read: [Guice Managed Action Beans](http://kdeveloper.com/guice-managed-action-beans/). It would look like this:

```
public class MyAction implements ActionBean {

  private final MySingleton mySingleton;

  @Inject
  MyAction(MySingleton mySingleton) {
    this.mySingleton = mySingleton;
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much @KDevelopr for the immediate response. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: @Kdeveloper, Do we have to use the Injector.getInstance() method call to instantiate the object in action beans ? or can we save the object in the context by creating a custom actionbeancontext ?

Comment: You should use inject them in either the actionBean or context with the @Inject annotation. Please see the link: http://kdeveloper.com/guice-managed-action-beans/

Comment: @Kdeveloper, In that example you did not implement the ActionBean interface. Then how it is supposed to work ?

Comment: @Kdeveloper, Now it is working properly. Thank you very much for your advice; but still the above doubt I have asked exists. How is it possible to work without implementing Actionbean interface ?

Comment: You right, I forgot to add the ActionBean interface in the example code (I have updated the example).